# Quickblox push notification not working with Firebase device token

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I'm using Quickblox for chatting features in my app, GCM was setup properly and it was fully functional along with push notification of Quickblox. But now [google developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) strongly recommends that GCM users should migrate to FCM. After migration to FCM, i noticed that device token ids are not in the same format as I was getting while using GCM. So what I'm facing now is my all other push notifications are working other than **Quickblox push notification** and I think the reason behind this is device token identifiers. Did anyone has faced such issue? Please help me here.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how to help exactly. Basically, you need to migrate to FCM and migrate to the 3.2 version of Quickblox if you didn't. I'll enumerate the main steps:

1. Follow the Google guide to migrate from GCM to FCM.
2. Integrate auto-push subscription and FCM Service. Insert in the manifest:

   ```
   <meta-data android:name="com.quickblox.messages.TYPE" android:value="FCM" />
   <meta-data android:name="com.quickblox.messages.SENDER_ID" android:value="@string/sender_id" />
   <meta-data android:name="com.quickblox.messages.QB_ENVIRONMENT" android:value="DEVELOPMENT" />

   <service
      android:name="com.quickblox.messages.services.fcm.QBFcmPushListenerService">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
       </intent-filter>
   </service>
   ```
3. Receive the events with something like this:

   ```
       private BroadcastReceiver pushBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               String message = intent.getStringExtra(“message”);
               String from = intent.getStringExtra("from");
               Log.i(TAG, "Receiving message: " + message + ", from " + from);
           }
       };

       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(pushBroadcastReceiver,
               new IntentFilter("new-push-event"));
   ```

I find this is the minimum required code to run. But better if you take a look at the Quickblox docs and understand their approach.

I get the impression that their docs isn't growing consistently with their code... This issue can break down the platform :(

https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android#Steps_to_setup_SDK_Settings.

> Remember insert your FCM Server key instead of the Legacy server key in Quickblox: `Your App > Push Notifications > Settings`.